# how i can authenticate Facebook access token using xmppstream object in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am developing Facebook chat application using  xmppframework.I got Facebook access token but
this access is not authenticate by xmppstream object:

Here is my `setupStream` method

```
- (void)setupStream
{
   XMPPStream *xmppStream=[[XMPPStream alloc] initWithFacebookAppId:@"443170809037796"];
}
```

here is my connection method

```
-(BOOL)connect1
{
    NSLog(@"connect1");
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![xmppStream isDisconnected]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"isDisconnected");
        return YES;
    } 
    if (![xmppStream connect:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting fb" 
                                                            message:@"See console for error details."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];   
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

here is my `xmppStreamDidconnect` delegate method for authentication

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    isXmppConnected = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken:[defaults             objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] error:&error];        
}
```

when  I run this app I am getting the fallowing error

**didNotAuthenticate**

Can any one solve my problem plz.

Comment: If you solved the problem, comment please. I also have a problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

facebook chat uses secure connection thus connect method  should look like this

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    isXmppConnected = YES;

    NSError *error = nil;
    //facebook connection
    if (_streamType == AAConnectStreamTypeFacebook) {

        if (![xmppStream isSecure])
        {

            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL result = [xmppStream secureConnection:&error];

            if (result == NO)
            {
                DDLogError(@"%@: Error in xmpp STARTTLS: %@", THIS_FILE, error);

            }
        }
        else
        {

            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL result = [xmppStream authenticateWithFacebookAccessToken:FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken error:&error];

            if (result == NO)
            {
                DDLogError(@"%@: Error in xmpp auth: %@", THIS_FILE, error);

            }
        }
    }
    else if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {

        DDLogError(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is that "_streamType == AAConnectStreamTypeFacebook" i'm getting error in this

Comment: its stream type class variable, because if you use any other service like google chat its  different connection/auth mode

Comment: how to send message from application to fb?

Comment: you should read the FBConnect documentation and xmpp documentation.. you have to understand whole logic

Answer (score 0):

```
http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/


 http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app
```

How to authenticate the user with the Graph API

How OAuth Authentication Works
To authenticate users to Facebook, the Graph API uses the new OAuth 2.0 protocol. Don’t worry – the name sounds imposing, but the way it works is actually pretty simple.
The idea is you make an app using the Facebook developer’s portal, and when you do you get a unique ID for your app called an API Key.
Then when you want to log a user into Facebook, you go to the following URL in a web browser:
     https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=[your API key]&
    redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&
    scope=[extended permissions you want]&
    type=user_agent&
    display=touch
The user will see a standard Facebook login page and they can enter in their username and password, and give any permissions required.
You don’t need to implement a redirect_uri yourself – you can just use a preset one from Facebook, as shown above. The preset callback will return to you an access token, which is what you’ll need to make all future requests.
When a user logs in, Facebooks stores some information about the login in cookies. So next time you try to login, if the cookies haven’t expired, the login will automatically complete without user intervention!